# buddypress registration page

Tags: registration, buddypress

I have setup a homepage, which shows a login, however I want the registration form to be on that page as well

The homepage is http://make-your-offer.com

And the register page is shown here http://make-your-offer.com/register/

I want the registration / confirmation etc all to be run from that page..

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just got a piece of code from http://pastebin.com/rgJ6BQc8 that may help you with this case.

Answer (score 1):

simple, just go to Buddypress/pages in the admin dashboard, and set the Registeration page to homepage..